Distribution of minimum number in sample (with replacement)
A box contains seven black balls numbered $1, 2, \ldots, 7$ and three white balls numbered $8, 9, 10$. Five balls are randomly selected with replacement. What would be the distribution of the minimum number in the sample?
I tried the following, where $X$ is the random variable denoting the minimum number in the sample:
\begin{align*}
P(X=1) &= \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{10}{10}\right)^4\binom{5}{1} \\
P(X=2) &= \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^4\binom{5}{1} \\
P(X=3) &= \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^4\binom{5}{1}
\end{align*}
and similarly for $X=4$ and $X=5$. However, I know this is incorrect as $\sum P(X=i) > 1$. What is the correct distribution?

What difference does the color make?

I don't think the color would make a difference

As to the distribution of the min, It's easier to get the probability  $P_m=P(X≤m)$ for $m\in {1, \cdots, 10}$.  Then the probability that $X=m$ is $P_m-P_{m-1}$

So, I suggest removing that from the problem.  Just to avoid confusion.

@lulu: even easier to get $Q_m =\mathbb P(X >m)$ and then say $\mathbb P(X =m)=Q_{m-1}-Q_m$

Would $P(X \leq m) = \left(\frac{m}{10}\right)^5$?

@CyberFrenzy No: $\left(\frac{m}{10}\right)^5$ is the probability that all the values are $\le m$, i.e. that the maximum is $\le m$

@Henry  Right, I'm persistently thinking of the max.

@CyberFrenzy  What I described is the way to get the distribution of the max, Henry is right that if you want the min you should work with the probability that $X≥m$.

So, $Q_m = P(X > m) = \left(1 - \left(\frac{m}{10}\right)^5\right)$ ?
Then, $P(X = m) = P(X > m - 1) - P(X > m)$.

To have the minimum $X≥m$ you need every selection to be $≥m$.  As there are $11-m$ numbers $≥m$ in the range, the probability that every selection is $≥m$ is $\left(\frac {11-m}{10}\right)^5$.

Worth noting:  Replacing each element $i$ by $11-i$ interchanges max and min, so getting one distribution does tell you the other.  But as you want the min, it's best to go directly for it.

You are asking for the minimum order statistic for a sample of size $n = 5$ from a discrete uniform distribution on $\{1, \ldots, 10\}$.  That is, you want $$X_{(1)} = \min_i X_i$$ where $X_i \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1,10)$.  To this end, note $$\Pr[X_{(1)} \ge x] = \Pr\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X_i \ge x)\right] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \Pr[X_1 \ge x]^n.$$
Since we have
$$\Pr[X_1 = x] = \frac{1}{10}, \quad x \in \{1, \ldots, 10\},$$
we also have
$$\Pr[X_1 \ge x] = \frac{10-x+1}{10}, \quad x \in \{1, \ldots, 10\}.$$  Thus
$$\Pr[X_{(1)} \ge x] = \left(\frac{10-x+1}{10}\right)^n$$
and
$$\Pr[X_{(1)} = x] = \Pr[X_{(1)} \ge x] - \Pr[X_{(1)} \ge x+1] = \frac{(11-x)^n - (10-x)^n}{10^n}.$$
For $n = 5$, this becomes
$$\Pr[X_{(1)} = x] = \frac{(11-x)^5 - (10-x)^5}{10^5}, \quad x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}.$$  We may then construct a table with explicit probabilities:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \Pr[X_{(1)} = x] \\
\hline
 1 & \frac{40951}{100000} \\
 2 & \frac{26281}{100000} \\
 3 & \frac{15961}{100000} \\
 4 & \frac{9031}{100000} \\
 5 & \frac{4651}{100000} \\
 6 & \frac{2101}{100000} \\
 7 & \frac{781}{100000} \\
 8 & \frac{211}{100000} \\
 9 & \frac{31}{100000} \\
 10 & \frac{1}{100000} \\
\end{array}$$
